# How to have missing() parameter also be missing in recursive call when the parameter has a default value?

Tags: r, recursion, lazy-evaluation

My R function uses `missing()` to switch between two alternative ways of specifying input data. However, if the input is a `factor`, I want to automatically apply the function on the factor levels instead, so I make a recursive call. Now I have the problem that I forward all arguments to the recursive call, so none of the parameters are missing anymore! How do I make a recursive call with all the parameters missing that are also missing in the parent call?

Minimal example:

```r
f <- function(a, b = 1){
  print(missing(b))
  if(length(a)>0) f(a = a[-1], b = b)
}
```

`f(1:2)` prints:

```
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
```

What I want is

```r
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
```

This works when b has no default value, so `f` is instead

```r
f <- function(a, b){
...
```

Also of course I have the option to switch the recursive call using `if(missing(b))`

```r
if(missing(b)) f(a = a[-1]) else f(a = a[-1], b = b)
```

... but this gets complicated for multiple parameters and also deprives me of the option to learn something about the strange wonders of parameter handling in R ;-)

Comment: instead of using missing, you can pass a `NULL` by default to `b`, and check if it is not null inside. The `NULL` will remain NULL even when you make recursive calls.

Comment: This is true, but my function is a translation function that uses a vector as dictionary. A NULL, being (very similar to) an empty vector, would mean a corner case of an empty set of translations, i.e. the output should be the same as the input. Giving a special meaning to NULL would make the function's interface more complicated

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the call with `match.call`, and substitute `a` for `a[-1]` in the call. Then instead of calling the function with arguments, use `do.call`, which will only supply the arguments initially put into the function in the recursive calls.

```r
f <- function(a, b = 1){
  print(missing(b))
  
  call_list <- as.list(match.call())[-1]

  if(length(a) > 0) {
    a <- a[-1]
    call_list$a <- a
    do.call(f, call_list)
  }
}

f(1:2)
#> [1] TRUE
#> [1] TRUE
#> [1] TRUE
```